# How I choose switches' logic to interact with an MCU in my own PCB?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, gpio, button, gpio-external-interrupt

I want to add a tactile switch to interact with my MCU (using a GPIO) to add flexibility in using and debugging my PCB. My question is, is there any preference on adding the switch (N.O. type) in active low or high? Is it better to connect it to Ground and set a 0 when it is holded or is it better to set a logic 1 when the user pushes it?

Comment: Many would say it's better to arrange them in a matrix to reduce IO count.

Comment: Although not directly related to your question, you should consider things like ESD and debouncing whenever you design in a tact switch. Each of these may or may not add a need for extra passives in the switch circuit.

Comment: I prefer switching to ground. I use a pull up resistor low enough in voltage to force at least 1mA through the switch contacts. If the micro has pull ups built in turn them off. With the pull up connected to the switch I then use a resistor from that point to the port pin, this protects from ESD etc. This extra current helps keep the contacts free of oxidation which is an insulator. If you do not do this you need to use switches rated as dry contact.

Comment: Which elements should I add to avoid ESD? @Lundin

Comment: @Gil So you are saying that I must use an external pull up resistor (for example, 10K connected to +3,3V) instead of using the internal one, with the goal of avoiding oxidation and improving ESD behaviour. Did I understand you?

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Usually done with a series resistor (10k or so) to the pin, which will also protect against other nasty stuff like accidental current rushes. Not to be confused with drawing current through a pull resistor which isn't related to ESD but to prevent oxidation. And obviously avoid using internal and external pull resistors at the same time.

Comment: Also you need to stop asking "what is better" while leaving everyone in the dark regarding what kind of application this is. Ruggedness vs current consumption is always a conflict and how to optimize it depends on the type of application.

Comment: @Lundin according to that you would have one 10K series resistor (for ESD) and one 10K pull up resistor (to avoid oxidation and set logic behaviour), both placed between the swtich and the MCU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the switch is connected to ground with a pullup.

There are a few (not necessarily strong) reasons for doing it that way, in many ways there is little difference).

- If ESD makes its way to a pin then ground is better than Vdd (this is
  an argument for some series resistance to the input in addition,
  otherwise the GPIO takes a beating).
- We can use an internal pullup in the MCU (see above) also many newer
  MCUs have both options available. Also internal pullups tend to be of
  marginal strength for EMC and switch wetting purposes. But the user
  can just press it again harder if it's just a toy or whatever.
- If the switches are off on another PCB with wiring and connections, an accidental short to ground with the switch closed will not damage the switch (again, a bit weak).

Comment: You'd probably want to counter ESD with a series resistor or similar no matter signal polarity.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you for you reply. I don't fully understand the second bullet point. Is it better to use external or internal resistors? What is that about "switch wetting purposes"?

Comment: For minimum parts, internal, but you are stuck with the (high resistance) value the chip designers picked, which is often not ideal and has typically a large tolerance. Switch “wetting” refers to a minimum switched current (typical 10uA to some mA, depending on the switch contact materials and construction- wiping vs. not). The switch datasheet should specify a minimum current as well as a maximum.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is there any preference on adding the switch (N.O. type) in active low or high?

Generally, no.

There is a special case depending on how much current you plan to draw through it. If you draw more current than the GPIO pin limit of the MCU, then it might matter if you choose to source (active high) or sink (active low) current, because some GPIO peripherals have different characteristics between sourcing and sinking.

As for why one would like to draw current through a switch - for example industrial applications often do that to counter oxidation, as a reliability at the cost of current draw optimization. (However, tact switches aren't really that suitable for industrial applications in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to activate internal pull up or pull down device on the GPIO pin. This is usually possible in most MCUs. Generally voltage level high in on and low is off. You may want to keep the voltage level of the pin low initially. When you have a discrete switch like this, you may also have to debounce the signal depending on your system requirements.

The signal coming to the GPIO pin from the switch would be a pulse looking like a step function with some ripple at the rising edge. In order to balance the voltage at the ripple, debouncing may be necessary.

Comment: You are talking about software debouncing, right? Is there any other (complementary way) of improving debouncing by hardware?

Comment: Hardware debouncing is done with a pull up resistor which is connected to a capacitor and a GPIO pin.  It looks like a RC low pass filter with a pull up resistor  which pulls the wire up to voltage of the MCU. This circuit is connected to the GPIO pin when the switch is ON.

Comment: Something like this, I guess: https://hackaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/debounce-sch.png
But, when the user pushes the bottom the voltage divider will set 0,3V to the GPIO, isn't that a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. GPIOs can be triggered at a low or high level so it doesn't seem a problem. Check the manual of your MCU to see what voltage will trigger a GPIO pin and if 0.3V falls in that range. It may be that it requires atleast half like 1.8V if your MCU voltage is 3.3V.

Comment: The hackaday circuit seems wrong. There are two ways to do this. One with switch logic high as ON and switch logic low as ON. Check this circuit. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/switch-bounce-how-to-deal-with-it/